# Datamining taking multiple variables

Tags: histograms, data-mining

We have gotten a list of data that includes grades from random students between 0 and 20. Now we want to seperate them into groups from 0 to 5 and 6 to 10 etc and make a histogram out of that to see what the influence of those grades are on the final grade of each student. so far we got this:

```
gradeAndG1 = Transpose[{G3,G1}];
gradeAndG10 = Select[gradeAndG1 ,Last[#] == 0 &];
gradeAndG11 = Select[gradeAndG1 ,Last[#] == 1 &];
gradeAndG12 = Select[gradeAndG1 ,Last[#] == 2 &];
gradeAndG13 = Select[gradeAndG1 ,Last[#] == 3 &];
gradeAndG14 = Select[gradeAndG1 ,Last[#] == 4 &];
gradeAndG15 = Select[gradeAndG1 ,Last[#] == 5 &];
gradeAndG16 = Select[gradeAndG1 ,Last[#] == 6 &];
gradeAndG17 = Select[gradeAndG1 ,Last[#] == 7 &];
gradeAndG18 = Select[gradeAndG1 ,Last[#] == 8 &];
gradeAndG19 = Select[gradeAndG1 ,Last[#] == 9 &];
gradeAndG110 = Select[gradeAndG1 ,Last[#] == 10 &];
gradeAndG111 = Select[gradeAndG1 ,Last[#] == 11 &];
gradeAndG112 = Select[gradeAndG1 ,Last[#] == 12 &];
gradeAndG113 = Select[gradeAndG1 ,Last[#] == 13 &];
gradeAndG114 = Select[gradeAndG1 ,Last[#] == 14 &];
gradeAndG115 = Select[gradeAndG1 ,Last[#] == 15 &];
gradeAndG116 = Select[gradeAndG1 ,Last[#] == 16 &];
gradeAndG117 = Select[gradeAndG1 ,Last[#] == 17 &];
gradeAndG118 = Select[gradeAndG1 ,Last[#] == 18 &];
gradeAndG119 = Select[gradeAndG1 ,Last[#] == 19 &];
gradeAndG120 = Select[gradeAndG1 ,Last[#] == 20 &];
Histogram[{gradeAndG10[[1;;,1]],gradeAndG11[[1;;,1]],gradeAndG12[[1;;,1]],gradeAndG13[[1;;,1]],gradeAndG14[[1;;,1]],gradeAndG15[[1;;,1]],gradeAndG16[[1;;,1]],gradeAndG17[[1;;,1]],gradeAndG18[[1;;,1]],gradeAndG19[[1;;,1]],gradeAndG110[[1;;,1]],gradeAndG111[[1;;,1]],gradeAndG112[[1;;,1]],gradeAndG113[[1;;,1]],gradeAndG114[[1;;,1]],gradeAndG115[[1;;,1]],gradeAndG116[[1;;,1]],gradeAndG117[[1;;,1]],gradeAndG118[[1;;,1]],gradeAndG119[[1;;,1]],gradeAndG120[[1;;,1]]},PlotLabel->"Grades period 1",ChartLegends->{"0-->5","6-->10","11-->15","16-->20"}]
```

Unfortunately this is a very unclear plot. A part of the data That we have to use is provided as a screenshot. The grades we are talking about are G1 and G2 and the final grade is G3. (The total list of grades is much larger but this is just a part of it for demonstration purposes.)

[image]

G1 = 
{
5
5
7
15
6
15
12
6
16
14
10
10
14
10
14
14
13
8
6
8
13
12
15
13
10
6
12
15
11
10
9
17
17
8
12
8
15
15
12
14
7
12
19
8
10
8
11
19
15
7
12
11
11
8
10
8
14
14
9
15
10
10
8
10
10
16
13
7
8
16
13
10
8
12
11
9
11
11
8
5
10
11
7
15
9
7
8
13
11
8
7
16
7
11
11
7
11
8
11
7
7
16
10
7
16
10
7
16
10
14
18
7
10
18
9
15
11
13
9
14
16
16
13
14
8
13
7
7
7
18
12
8
10
12
9
11
10
4
14
16
7
9
9
14
5
8
6
10
7
8
6
12
10
5
11
11
16
9
17
10
7
5
7
10
5
12
10
14
6
14
6
13
13
8
10
10
13
6
10
10
9
12
16
9
12
12
11
15
8
8
11
8
7
8
13
14
17
9
18
9
16
8
9
7
10
10
7
11
9
7
8
12
12
6
8
14
6
6
7
9
6
6
16
12
13
9
16
12
10
12
13
11
11
14
9
11
14
13
13
7
12
10
6
13
7
18
12
6
3
13
6
7
6
8
8
7
14
11
15
10
17
8
13
10
9
17
9
12
10
6
9
15
11
15
10
12
10
9
9
10
8
11
12
8
10
12
18
13
15
15
12
15
12
18
14
14
10
10
14
16
12
11
15
17
15
14
17
8
15
12
9
14
13
13
15
13
8
9
11
11
13
11
11
12
16
9
14
11
10
14
9
12
7
8
10
16
14
7
16
9
11
10
16
9
11
13
16
10
13
11
8
13
8
8
13
10
12
12
10
18
13
13
11
16
12
10
13
7
11
14
7
14
13
6
19
8
15
8
15
10
15
7
11
6
6
10
6
7
7
6
9
14
10
11
8};
    G2 = 
{
6
5
8
14
10
15
12
5
18
15
8
12
14
10
16
14
14
10
5
10
14
15
15
13
9
9
12
16
11
12
11
16
16
10
14
7
16
16
12
13
10
12
18
8
10
8
12
19
15
7
13
13
11
10
13
9
15
15
10
16
11
8
10
9
10
15
13
7
9
16
15
10
6
12
12
9
11
11
8
5
12
10
6
15
10
9
7
14
10
6
7
17
6
10
13
10
15
9
14
9
7
17
13
6
18
11
8
18
13
15
19
10
13
19
9
15
13
14
7
13
15
14
13
11
7
13
10
8
4
18
0
0
13
11
0
0
0
0
12
16
9
9
11
14
0
11
7
11
6
9
5
13
10
0
11
8
12
8
15
12
6
9
0
10
8
11
10
15
7
14
5
15
11
7
11
9
13
5
8
10
8
13
17
9
13
12
12
15
7
9
12
8
8
9
14
15
15
9
18
9
16
10
9
6
10
9
7
12
9
7
8
12
13
7
10
15
6
6
7
10
6
5
16
13
13
8
15
11
8
10
13
11
9
13
7
9
13
12
11
7
12
11
0
12
0
18
12
8
5
15
8
10
9
9
12
9
12
11
14
9
18
8
12
9
10
17
9
10
9
0
9
14
11
14
10
12
9
9
8
11
8
9
12
9
9
10
18
12
14
13
11
15
12
18
13
12
9
8
13
15
10
11
12
17
14
12
18
9
12
10
9
12
11
10
13
11
8
10
11
11
13
9
11
14
15
12
15
10
9
14
8
14
0
8
9
15
13
8
15
10
12
10
15
8
10
13
15
10
15
13
7
13
7
8
11
9
13
12
10
16
13
12
11
15
11
10
13
6
10
12
7
12
11
5
18
8
14
9
15
10
14
6
11
5
5
9
5
5
9
5
9
16
8
12
9};
    G3 = 
{
6
6
10
15
10
15
11
6
19
15
9
12
14
11
16
14
14
10
5
10
15
15
16
12
8
8
11
15
11
11
12
17
16
12
15
6
18
15
11
13
11
12
18
11
9
6
11
20
14
7
13
13
10
11
13
10
15
15
9
16
11
11
9
9
10
15
12
6
8
16
15
10
5
14
11
10
10
11
10
5
12
11
6
15
10
8
6
14
10
7
8
18
6
10
14
10
15
10
14
8
5
17
14
6
18
11
8
18
13
16
19
10
13
19
9
16
14
13
8
13
15
15
13
13
8
12
11
9
0
18
0
0
12
11
0
0
0
0
12
15
0
9
11
13
0
11
0
11
0
10
0
14
10
0
12
8
13
10
15
12
0
7
0
10
7
12
10
16
0
14
0
16
10
0
9
9
11
6
9
11
8
12
17
8
12
11
11
15
9
10
13
9
8
10
14
15
16
10
18
10
16
10
10
6
11
9
7
13
10
7
8
13
14
8
10
15
4
8
8
10
6
0
17
13
14
7
15
12
9
12
14
11
9
13
6
10
13
12
11
0
12
12
0
12
0
18
13
8
5
15
8
10
8
8
12
8
13
11
14
0
18
8
12
9
0
17
10
11
10
0
9
14
11
14
10
12
9
9
8
10
8
10
12
10
11
11
19
12
14
15
11
15
13
18
14
11
0
8
14
16
11
10
14
18
13
12
18
8
12
10
0
13
11
11
13
11
0
9
10
11
13
9
11
15
15
11
16
10
9
14
8
14
0
0
0
15
13
0
17
10
11
0
15
0
10
14
16
9
15
13
8
13
8
8
11
9
13
11
10
16
13
12
10
15
12
10
13
0
10
11
9
12
11
5
19
10
15
10
15
10
14
7
10
0
5
10
6
0
8
0
9
16
7
10
9};

All help will be greatly appreciated.
Kind regrads,
Didier Drogba professional football player and data mining physicist

Comment: Could you please post `G3` and `G1` somewhere?

Comment: Copied from the image of the table (sorry, not too sure how to format this better):

    `G1 = {5, 5, 7, 15, 6, 15, 12, 6, 16, 14, 10, 10, 14, 10, 14, 14, 13, 
       8, 6, 8, 13, 12, 15, 13, 10, 6, 12, 15, 11, 10, 9, 17, 17, 8};`
    
    `G2 = {6, 5, 8, 14, 10, 15, 12, 5, 18, 15, 8, 12, 14, 10, 16, 14, 14, 
       10, 5, 10, 14, 15, 15, 13, 9, 9, 12, 16, 11, 12, 11, 16, 16, 10};`
    
    `G3 = {6, 6, 10, 15, 10, 15, 11, 6, 19, 15, 9, 12, 14, 11, 16, 14, 14, 
       10, 5, 10, 15, 15, 16, 12, 8, 8, 11, 15, 11, 11, 12, 17, 16, 12};`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have added G1, G2 and G3 to the post. unfortunately it is from an excel file so I don't know another way of posting it in a more convenient way than this.

Answer (score 1):

You may use [`DensityHistogram`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DensityHistogram.html) on the [`GroupBy`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GroupBy.html) grades.

I had to do some processing on your posted G1,G2,G3 as they are not correct syntax. They are missing the comma list separators but pasting as a string with a few replacements gets the lists. You should fix that.

In any case, with

```
byFinal = KeySort@GroupBy[Last -> Most]@Transpose@{g1, g2, g3};
```

Then

```
DensityHistogram[#, {1},
   PlotRange -> {{0, 20}, {0, 20}},
   ChartBaseStyle -> EdgeForm[{Thin, Gray}],
   ColorFunction -> ColorData[{"AvocadoColors", {1, 10}}],
   ColorFunctionScaling -> False
   ] & /@ byFinal
```

*Right-click and open image in new tab to enlarge*

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

The result above shows the distribution of G1 (x-axis) and G2 (y-axis) grades per G3 grade (density). It is pretty clear that there is a diagonal drift upwards from left to right has the G3 grade increases. So it seems the better you score in G1 and G2 then the better your G3 final grade will be.

The cells are tooltiped with their values by default but you can create a key with

```
BarLegend[{"AvocadoColors", {1, 10}}, Range@10, LegendLayout -> "Row"]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your help Edmund, it was exactly what we needed!